# Regular expression with placeholders

Tags: java, regex

I've got a string like this: "Hi $namevar$ how are you?". I want to:

1. extract the placeholder name
2. match against this string another string, for example "Hi jhon doe how are you?"
3. extract from the test string the "namevar" part

For 1) I'm using the following code:

```
String my = "hi $namevar$ how are you?";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\w.*?)\\$").matcher(my);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Any tips for 2) and 3)?

Comment: 2,3 rules are unclear for me. Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: For 2) I want true if the string is "hi john doe how are you?" so any character where is $namevar$. For 3) I want to get namevar="john doe"

Comment: Are you still interested in a more generic solution or have all your requirements been met?

Comment: @RaviThapliyal A generic solution would be good.

Comment: @greywolf82 Added my take on your requirements 2 and 3.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a more generic approach that doesn't require you to provide a *pattern*, works for multiple placeholders and can match a placeholder over multiple words too. Say, we have the following template and input string:

```
String input = "Hi John Doe, how are you? I'm Jane.";
String template = "Hi $namevar$, how are you? I'm $namevar2$.";
```

So, we parse all the placeholder names and add them to a `Map` first. We use a `Map` so that we can assign the actual `String` values as *keys* later on.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\w*?)\\$").matcher(template);
Map<String, String> vars = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    vars.put(m.group(1), null);
}
```

Now, we generate the *pattern* to parse placeholder values as

```
String pattern = template;
// escape regex special characters
pattern = pattern.replaceAll("([?.])", "\\\\$1");
for (String var : vars.keySet()) {
    // replace placeholders with capture groups
    pattern = pattern.replaceAll("\\$"+var+"\\$", "([\\\\w\\\\s]+?)");
}
```

Now, we make a *match* and capture the placeholder values. The values are then stored in the same `Map` created above, assigned to their corresponding placeholder variables.

```
m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    int i = 0;
    for (String var : vars.keySet()) {
        vars.put(var, m.group(++i));
    }
}
```

Now, let's print out our captured values by iterating over the `Map` as

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : vars.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

***Output :***

```
namevar = John Doe
namevar2 = Jane
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
String mydata = "hi john how are you?";
System.out.println(mydata.matches("hi (.*?) how are you\\?"));//requirement 2
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("hi (.*?) how are you?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));//requirement 3
}
Output:
true
john
```

Comment: How can I modify your code in order to use more than one placeholder?

Comment: `String mydata = "hi john how are you Mr. greyWolf?";Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("hi (.*?) how are you (.*?)\\?");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            int count = matcher.groupCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }`